# Excel what is the best practice to find a string then return a value in a table

Tags: excel

I want to make a report that extract data from two tables.

The report will contain the current date's data, the previous date's data, and the variance.

The report extracts the current date's data from table1, and the previous date's data from table2.
The two tables do not always have the same customer, but the report lists all the customers.
If no customer found in either table, zero will be returned.

I used `IF` and `VLOOKUP` to get a value linked to a customer, however it returns zero.
[image]

Also, it reads a wrong cell when a customer does not exist in either table.
For example, CustD does not exist in the Table2, nor CustE does not exist in the Table1.
The report has both the customers. When I put the formula in the Report, it tries to get a value in a wrong row. (Please see below picture)
[image]

What is the best practice to do this problem?
Can I perform this problem like I use SQL?? If so, how?

Comment: Look into using the Filter function and spill range.

Comment: @pgSystemTester my excel version is 2016. It does not have the Filter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [Link](https://www.get-digital-help.com/extract-unique-distinct-records-from-two-data-sets/) they seem to have what you are searching for.

Code for reference if link is broken:

```
B11: =IFNA(INDEX($B$3:$C$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIFS($B$10:B10, $B$3:$B$6), 0),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),(INDEX($E$3:$F$6,MATCH(0, COUNTIFS($B$10:B10, $E$3:$E$6), 0), COLUMNS($A$1:A1))))

C11: =IFNA(VLOOKUP($B11,$B$3:$C$6,2,FALSE),0)

D11: =IFNA(VLOOKUP($B11;$E$3:$F$6;2;FALSE);0)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much Runejm ! It worked perfectly.